# Is there a way to check for the [caller-specified-name] in the sts:RoleSessionName when federated login is used?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I would like to check for the `RoleSessionName` when a assume-role is done, like in this example:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      ...
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "sts:RoleSessionName": "${aws:username}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Since we are using federated login the `aws:username` is not provided and I have to use `aws:userid`. The `aws:userid` is composed by `account` + `caller-specified-name`. I'm only interessed in the `caller-specified-name` and I want to check something like this:

```
{
  "Statement": [
    {
      ...
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "sts:RoleSessionName": "caller-specified-name"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If anyone knows how this could be done, I would be very happy :) Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for a substring like command?

Comment: Would be a solution if there is something like that, to do string manipulation within the policy (e.g. ${aws:username}.split(':')[1]). At the end of the day I want to check if the RoleSessionName is the caller-specified-name.